# Getting an error while finding the product of a Matrix

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

```
def getMatrixProduct(a, b):
    if len(a[0]) != len(b):
        return -1
    result = [[0 for i in range(len(b[0]))] for j in range(len(a))]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b[0])):
            for k in range(len(b)):
                result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
    return result
```

It is the code to find the product of two matrices but it is throwing the following error

```
result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: what is your input `a` and `b`?

Comment: The input could be any 2-D matrix

Comment: can u pass me the exact input for which you are getting the error. The code seems to work for me for a dummy matrix input.